# Should future question specific notes be placed on the bottom of the question?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

As seen on https://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/464257, there is a question specific note being displayed at the beginning:

> This question exists because it has
>   historical significance, but it is not
>   considered a good, on-topic question
>   for this site, so please do not use it
>   as evidence that you can ask similar
>   questions here.
>
> More info:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/faq

However, sites that scrape the content off of the page might show the question being only the note shown above; for example, attaching a link to a Facebook Post will show it as this:
[image]

Moving the note to the bottom would display the question contents rather than just the note itself. So, should future question specific notes be placed on the bottom of the question instead of the top?

Comment: Does it happen only in that case, or are there any other cases where the question text is not shown integrally?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, if you meant with only the message above verse other notes, I'm not sure, but the first three questions over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes give the same result.

Comment: The banner is an indication that the question doesn't really belong on the site in the first place. Should those questions be FaceBook linked at all? Also, many questions will need some tweaking anyway to get them to look properly in such a FaceBook link, as they will contain text like *"I hope I'm asking this question in the right place."* Is there a way to edit the FaceBook text, instead of trying to force the questions into a FaceBook format?

Comment: @Robert: I don't really care where it's from, if it's helpful and could be helpful to others, I would like to share it. Would be a plus if it showed the actual question as well, instead of showing a what would seem to be over moderated message to users that may have never been to a Stack Exchange site before.

Comment: As a tangential point, that message actually kinda exists exactly for such users who may have never been to a Stack Exchange site before.

Comment: @Grace: Which is why I never said to remove it, just move it.

Comment: Looks good as a warning banner before they click through and think that the site is all about that. Read now before the click through and stop reading.

Comment: @Robert I see your point. Perhaps I should change the title to: "*Should future question specific notes be placed on the bottom of the question?*"

Comment: Alright, I'm going to leave the "free programming books" question in its original form while we get some community consensus.  And yes, that's probably a better title for this question.

Comment: I don't think questions that are possible duplicates show that they are in Google.

Comment: We need *archive.stackoverflow.com* where these sorts of ridiculous questions can go (not this meta question, but the one linked to fb)!

Answer (score 8):

You could have just edited the post in the publisher.
Problem solved for Facebook.

[image: Here is the highlighted portion]

[image: And the edit]

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm an active user on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) [facebook] tag</sub>

Comment: That's what I thought. This is the simplest solution; problem solved.

Comment: If the question itself is put into the META description tag, this problem would go away too. Facebook will read the META tag first before taking the first paragraph.

Comment: @bra this means we serve up millions of bytes nobody will see on *every single page view* just on the chance Facebook will need it sometime later. Not a fan of that ...

Comment: @Jeff: What about an excerpt?

Answer (score 1):

If you move it to the bottom, you'd have to move the Possible Duplicate box to the bottom too. I don't think that is good from a usability standpoint. However, it would be nice if you could add a special tag to a DIV so that facebook only used that summary. It is used on some news sites so I don't know how they do it, but facebook must obey it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The whole user note at the top of a post was a mega hack. It was abolished in favo[u]r of post notices.

Post notices are at the bottom.